# Azure Data Lake Service-to-service authentication client secret, AdalServiceException and WebException

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake, azure-authentication

Tyring to use the below docs to get this up and running for my console app that I plan to port to Azure Functions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk

The code below is where I'm getting stuck

**CODE SNIP**

```
// Service principal / appplication authentication with client secret / key
// Use the client ID of an existing AAD "Web App" application.
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

var domain = "<AAD-directory-domain>";
var webApp_clientId = "<AAD-application-clientid>";
var clientSecret = "<AAD-application-client-secret>";
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(webApp_clientId, clientSecret);
var creds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domain, clientCredential);
```

**MY IMPLEMENTATION**

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
var domain = "https://microsoft.onmicrosoft.com";
var webApp_clientId = "<my-client-id>";
var clientSecret = "<my-client-secret>";
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(webApp_clientId, clientSecret);
var creds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domain, clientCredential);

SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());                       

_adlsClient = new DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(creds) { SubscriptionId = _subId };
_adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);

await _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.MkdirsAsync("<name-of-my-dlstore>", "tempdir");
```

I also made sure to give my app permissions to my specified folder in Azure Data Lake instance:
[image]

I also made sure to give all child folders in this directory the same level or permissions:
[image]

Assigned permissions to file path

[image]

When I run my implementation I get the below errors. Any advice SO?
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'

Inner Exception 1

AdalServiceException: AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier 'https:' is not valid.

Trace ID: d1718b0a-0533-4708-a311-4e1622840100

Correlation ID: a1544df2-692e-43d2-8acf-25a847956fb6

Timestamp: 2017-03-29 01:30:18Z

Inner Exception 2

WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

**AS PART OF SOLUTION**
Need to make sure to give root folder read, write, execute permissions, (this will trickle down to the one folder you want to give these permissions for) then remove those permissions from all other folders you don't want these permissions assigned too, making sure you select the option to remove these permissions for that sub folder and all it's kiddos/children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > AdalServiceException: AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier 'https:' is not valid.

That is your tenant name ,like "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com" .

> > WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

What is the detail error message , please refer to tutorial :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk

I followed the detail steps to use service-to-service authentication with client secret , and successfully create a directory .  Code below is for your reference :

```
  public static async Task  CreateDirectory()
    {

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
        var domain = "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com";
        var webApp_clientId = "client id";
        var clientSecret = "client secret";
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(webApp_clientId, clientSecret);
        var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domain, clientCredential).Result;

        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

        _adlsClient = new DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(creds) { SubscriptionId = "_subId" };
        _adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);

        await _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.MkdirsAsync("_adlsAccountName", "tempdir");

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateDirectory().Wait();
    }
```

**EDIT**

You need to assign **Execute** permission to your app if you want to create a directory  . Tenant ID and tenant name are both available ,means :

```
 var domain = "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com";
 //you could also use tenant id 
 var domain = "Your tenant ID";
```

Comment: Thanks! This snip was a step forward in that I corrected my domain string and used your syntax for creds by capturing the .Result, but now I', experiencing a different error.

Comment: System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.' Inner Exception | AdlsErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Comment: Have you assigned the permissions as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-authenticate-using-active-directory)

Comment: Yes, but only READ and WRITE permissions. Do I also need EXECUTE permissions? I also see some need to "When programmatically logging in, you need to pass the tenant ID with your authentication request. " here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-id), but not sure how to do this as I don't see syntax on how to do this in code snips from the tutorials I've been following.

Comment: @GregDegruy ,i have edited my answer to reply your question ,please check it .

Comment: perfect! last thing, I only have these permissions to a specific folder not the entire Azure Data Lake for my app, could I do something like to complete this, I think my syntax is off somewhere since I am getting a "AdlsErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'" `await _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.MkdirsAsync("<name-of-my-dlstore>", @"dirAppHasPermissionsTo\NewDir");` Do I need to include the full path somehow to ensure this `adl://<name-of-my-dlstore>.azuredatalakestore.net`

Comment: You also need to assign permission for app to access "dirAppHasPermissionsTo" folder : click the folder , click "Access" button and assign related permissions to your app . You could also choose add to "This folder and all children" when assign permission , if you want the app to have permissions in the children of the folder.

Comment: And don't need to use full path :  await _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.MkdirsAsync("nanyutest", @"tempdir11\tempdir11");

Comment: @Greg Degruy , have you solved your problem ? If yes, please mark this reply as answer , so that could help others who meet same problem .If any other issue ,feel free to let me known .

Comment: all the advice given so far is spot on, I just stink lol. I've uploaded the console app in a temp.zip file in my repo if you'd like to take a further look ( https://github.com/gregdegruy/bigdataanalytics-azurefunction - specific to the `DataLakeService.cs` Class) I am still getting this error `AdlsErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'`, I'll update my images in my question post to show the permissions assigned to my App for this Data Lake Folder and it's children as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139319/discussion-between-nan-yu-msft-and-greg-degruy).

Comment: var domain = "Your tenant ID"; worked for me.. :)